# List comprehension showing numbers in a weird format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

| Transaction | Transaction Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Deposit | 10.00 |
| Dividend | 0.9 |
| Taxes | 0.04 |

And I am applying a list comprehension like this:

```
df['Tax'] = ['0' if i == "Deposit" or i == "Dividend" else df['Transaction Amount'] for i in df['Transaction']]


df['Net Amount'] = [df['Transaction Amount'] if i == "Deposit" or i == "Dividend" else -1 * df['Tax'] for i in df['Transaction']]
```

However, for both I get a weird output like this: "0 1.00 1 1000.00 2 1000.00 3..."

Transaction Amount is a float64, I have tried to make it string, to see if that solves the issue, but I keep getting the same.

Comment: Will you please provide a dataframe containing the output you expect?

Comment: Man, '0' is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `np.where` instead of list comprehension.

```
import numpy as np
df['Tax'] = np.where(df['Transaction'].isin(['Deposit', 'Dividend']),
                     0 ,df['Transaction Amount'])

df['Net Amount'] = np.where(df['Transaction'].isin(['Deposit', 'Dividend']), 
                            df['Transaction Amount'], -1*df['Tax'])
```

Output:

```
  Transaction  Transaction Amount   Tax  Net Amount
0     Deposit               10.00  0.00       10.00
1    Dividend                0.90  0.00        0.90
2       Taxes                0.04  0.04       -0.04
```